# Inserting Google analytic Code into website

Tags: html, analytics, google-analytics-sdk

I am using site kit Builder and its ready to use templates for my website. I now wish to install Google Analytics.
I have copied and pasted the tracking code snippet into my header (left of share button) by "Embedding Code". However, Google keeps saying that tracking code is not installed. 
Since I am using templates, I dont have any   tags. I am totally stumped about what to do. Please help.

Website address: [www.inccs.in](http://www.inccs.in)

Comment: Have you checked real-time reports for your own visits?  It takes up to 48 hours to start seeing data in your standard reports.

Answer (score 0):

You have your GA code installed three times on your site.  This may be causing conflicts.  Make sure you only have one instance installed.

Comment: Multiple instances of the same tracking code wouldn't cause conflicts, I believe (but definitely good point to rectify that). It would just inflate the page hits. I think the issue OP is referring to may have more to do with a "fresh" installation of the tracking code, and would need to wait for data to be processed in the standard reports.